# Adding a piece of international law to BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, citing, legal-style

How do I add:

> UN General Assembly, Universal Declaration of Human Rights, art. 12, 10 December 1948, 217 A (III), available at: http://www.refworld.org/docid/3ae6b3712c.html [accessed 17 February 2015]

to BibTeX? I am new to this, I am not sure how the entry should look like.

Here is what I came up with:

```
@misc{unart12,
  title={Universal Declaration of Human Rights},
  author={UN General Assembly},
  month={December},
  year={1948},
  note={Art. 12, Available at: http://www.unhchr.ch/udhr/lang/eng.pdf [accessed 17 February 2015]}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which illustrates whatever problem you are having when you try to add a `.bib` entry for this. Right now, it isn't at all clear to me what exactly you are having trouble with.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using `biblatex` and its `online` entry type.

Comment: @Bernard Isn't `online` meant for inherently online sources? This isn't in that category. I think there are really 2 options: if you need to add many legal references, you need a style designed to support that; if you just need to add one or two, you can usually fiddle enough with the entries to get them formatted acceptably (but then this depends on the style you are using). But `biblatex`/`biber` is always a good idea if that's an option.

Comment: You are mixing up 2 methods of managing your references. In one, you format the entries manually using `\bibitem` etc. In the other, you add them to a `.bib` file and use `bibtex` or `biblatex`/`biber` to create your bibliography based on the database in the `.bib` file.

Comment: @cfr I am trying to cite article 12 of the UN DHR in my article. As such, I want to add it to my bibtex db. However, I am not sure what it is :( Is it an `@article` or a `@misc`? I know what the APA format should look like, but just not sure how to add it as an entry in mybib file.

Comment: See my comment above responding to Bernard's. In any case, please post an MWE.

Comment: I would use the `misc` entry type and the `url` field. There exists a `legal` entry type, but it is unsupported and it would be up to you define required and optional entrys and how to format them.

Comment: Probably `@misc`. That seems to be what I'm using for legal entries. (Or `@juristiction` but that is not a standard field for `bibtex` and is probably mapped to `@misc` anyway.) The `note` field is probably essential (for `bibtex`).

Comment: @cfr I have added some code. Please let me know if that is correct.

Comment: @cfr made some editions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my entry for the Universal Declaration of Human Rights:

```
@misc{udhr,
        organization                    =       {{United Nations}},
        publisher                       =       {Office of the United Nations High Commissioner for Human Rights},
        title                           =       {Universal Declaration of Human Rights},
        year                            =       1948,
        day                             =       10,
        month                           =       dec}
```

Add a `url` field for the web address and put the date accessed in the `note` field, probably. If you need to add the article to the entry (rather than the citation), you might use the `note` field there, too.

```
        url                             =       {http://www.unhchr.ch/udhr/lang/eng.pdf},
        note                            =       {Art. 12. Accessed 17 February 2015}}
```

Comment: Note that `biblatex` would give you more flexibility 'out of the box'.

Comment: The compilation failed because there wasn't any author or key, so it couldn't sort. Once I added a `key` element. It worked fine! Cheers :)

Comment: @codehitman That is why you should have posted an MWE. Then I would have tested it with *your* setup. This has worked fine for me, but then I'm probably using different packages etc. (Well, now I'm using `biblatex` but the entry is from my `bibtex` usage.)